# Particle Emittor and Collections - Can't understand why

Tags: animation, particles

I'm following a tutorial to make these berries blast in the air around the bottle. Now, I duplicated a couple of berries and added a water droplet and moved them all into the same collection. I kept the original berry, the one with the particle system outside this collection (named Berries). The tutorial then says to create a mesh that will act as an emitter and assign it the same particle system of the first berry but creating a new instance of it. The emitter mesh is emitting something but it is very delayed and doesn't make much sense if you look at the emitter settings. The strawberries in the collection all emit pieces of themselves.

Basically I want the emitter mesh to emit a mix of of strawberries randomly picked from a collection I made.

This is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2r6imiurWo&ab_channel=TopChannel1on1

The .blend file: https://easyupload.io/eypxtp - The site uploader doesn't accept mine although it is 29.8mb and I don't know what else to strip out of the project.

Comment: Hi everyone,

I still haven't found a solution anywhere. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Some tips to improve your chances. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

### A Few Tweaks

I downloaded your blend and got it looking closer to the tutorial by tweaking a few things.

#### Scale

Your particle system is working, but the particles are almost too small to see. First, always make sure your object's scale is applied. This means that its scale is set to `1.0` for `X` `Y` and `Z` otherwise you'll get unpredictable results. Apply the scale with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then select *Scale*.

[image]

Next, set the scale of the instances in the particle settings of your emitter *Properties > Particles > Render > Scale*. This one is important because I think the default size is pretty small.

[image]

Also make sure *Pick Random* is checked.

#### Each Particle is Also Exploding

Your source berries each have the explosion effect on them which means each and every particle is also exploding throughout the animation. I don't think that is desired. I deleted the `Explosion` particle system from the source berries.

#### Rotation

After this the particle berries were pointing all the same way so I added some randomness with *Properties > Particles > Rotation > Randomize*.

[image]

#### Gravity

Make sure *Gravity* is unchecked in the *Scene* tab of the *Properties* editor. It can be confusing that this setting is not within the *Particles* tab.

I also found that your strawberries shoot away from the emitter quite quickly so I lowered the Velocity with *Properties > Particles > Velocity > Normal*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer I really appreciate it! Everything work although even though the particle system has gravity set to 0, why do my strawberries fall shortly after the initial burst?

Comment: @TORM3NTO I updated the answer with a note about gravity. There is a separate gravity setting for the whole scene that must be unchecked